# Where can I buy a control set like NOD32 uses for its UI

Tags: antivirus

My boss wants our program to have fly-out menus with smooth transitions like ESET NOD Antivirus 4 has.

[alt text http://img808.imageshack.us/img808/1283/anitvirus.png](http://img808.imageshack.us/img808/1283/anitvirus.png)
Where can I buy a control set that has a similar look and feel to this? I have never bought a set before and I don't even know of what sites to start shopping at.

Comment: You looking to do a desktop GUI (what platforms?), emulate this on web, or what?  Any language/framework requirements?  There's not much to go on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DevComponents.com](http://www.DevComponents.com) has a super tab control as a part of it suite that looks very similar to what you want.  It's very inexpensive compared to other suites as well.  That is if you are using .NET WinForms.  You never specified.